# Unrelated deleted operator changes behaviour of overload resolution

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, namespaces, overload-resolution

I came across a strange situation today, where declaring a deleted operator with certain arguments changed the behaviour of seemingly unrelated code.

I reduced it to the following. Start with this:

```
namespace N 
{
    enum E { A, B };

    struct C 
    {   
        C(E);
    private:
        C(int);
    };  
}

N::E operator|(N::E, N::E);

namespace N
{
    void Waldo()
    {   
        C(A | B); 
    }   
}
```

Notice that C has two constructors, a public one and a private one. This code compiles, indicating that the public overload is being chosen, so the expression `A | B` has type `E`. In turn this means that the `operator|(N::E, N::E)` has been matched (otherwise `A` and `B` would undergo implicit conversion to integers, the type of `A | B` would be `int`, and the private constructor would be matched.

So far so good. Now I define a new enumeration type `F`, and a deleted `operator|` that involves F:

```
namespace N 
{
    enum E { A, B };

    struct C 
    {   
        C(E);
    private:
        C(int);
    };  
}

N::E operator|(N::E, N::E);

namespace N
{
    enum F {};
    int operator|(F, int) = delete; 

    void Waldo()
    {   
        C(A | B); 
    }   
}
```

Now the code doesn't compile, saying that `C(int)` is private. This indicates that now `A | B` has type `int`, which means `operator|(N::E, N::E)` is no longer being matched.

**Why did the addition of the deleted `operator|(F, int)` stop `operator|(N::E, N::E)` from being matched?**

Comment: The second operator is in the namespace `N`; the first one is in the global namespace.

Comment: Never trust an operator overload that is not declared in the namespace of the associated type. ADL exists to avoid exactly this kind of weirdness. [Compiles fine with the first operator declared in `N`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95cdffbbd85ca037 "Live code at Coliru").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, note that being declared as `delete`d is irrelevant, since deleted functions still take part in overload resolution.

Now, on to overload resolution. Cf. 13.3.1.2/3:

> three sets of candidate functions, designated *member candidates*, *nonmember
>   candidates* and *built-in candidates*, are constructed

(There are no member candidates, since `E` is not a class type.) We know from  that the operator overload is found by *unqualified lookup*. So when we consult 3.4.1 ("Unqualified lookup"), we find that

> name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.

Since you introduce the second operator overload within the namespace `N`, it is found first, and name lookup stops. At this point, the overload set consists of your `int N::operator|(N::F, int)` and the built-in operators. Continuing in 13.3.1.2/6:

> The set of candidate functions for overload resolution is the union of the member candidates, the non-member candidates, and the built-in candidates.

Only the builtin is viable (since you cannot convert `E` to `F` implicitly), and thus it is chosen.

Comment: So if name lookup for the `|` in `A | B` finds stops when `operator|(F, int)` is found, how does the built-in `operator|` end up being called?

Comment: @HighCommander4: It doesn't. Nobody is getting called. The type system is independent of the execution.

Comment: Excuse me if I language wasn't precise enough. The compiler gives an error saying `C(int)` is private, so it determines that the type of the expression `A | B` is `int`. How does it get that? The only reason I can think of is that it is matching the `|` in `A | B` to the built-in `operator|` for integers (and implicitly converting `A` and `B` to integers to match the parameter types of this built-in operator).

Comment: If that were the case, making `C(int)` public should result in a compiler error about calling a deleted function; it does not (tested with gcc 4.7).

Comment: @HighCommander4: Ah, right, apologies. So, your overload set consists of your operator| *and* the builtin operator for ints. Overload resolution then picks the builtin operator. Let me add that.

Comment: @HighCommander4: (Note that built-in operators aren't in any namespace. They're not functions and they don't have names.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is simple.

Put your `operator|` in the same namespace as the type.  Now, ADL (argument dependent lookup) kicks in, and it is found *even if* there is the unrelated `operator|` also visible.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/FepAte).  Note that `N::operator|` is found despite the `|` being used in `namespace Z`.

The proper place to overload free operators for a type is the `namespace` that the type lives in, not the global namespace.